# Trying to find a matching value using a key (C++)

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers, memory-leaks, function-definition

I am trying to look through my custom dictionary for a given const Key&. Once the Key is found, the matching Value needs to be returned as a const Value* instead of a Value. Currently, my code will compile but does not run as it crashes due to a memory leak so I am not even sure the code works as intended.

I've tried to delete my temp pointer but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe there is a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

mTable is a collection of lists of pairs(key, value)

```
const Value* Find(const Key& key) {
        /*int bucket = mHashFunc(_key);*/
        const Value* temp = nullptr;
        for (auto listIter = mTable[0].begin(); listIter != mTable[0].end(); ++listIter) {
            if (listIter->key == key) {
                temp = new Value(listIter->value);
            }
        }
        return temp;
        delete temp;
    }
```

Comment: `delete temp;` after `return temp;` is certainly an error. That line of code will never be executed. But also why do you _want_ to delete the object you're returning? Also why are you creating a new object at all instead of returning a pointer to the object you successfully found?

Comment: The object being deleted is to free the memory of the pointer to avoid a leak. As for the second part... I don't know it, its just the path I went, and why I asked if there was a different way to achieve what I want to do...

Comment: Even if the `delete temp;` was being run, what would be the point of deleting an object as soon as you returned on? How would anything that calls `Find` actually make use of the object if it's already been deleted?

Comment: My thought process was once it is returned, it doesn't need to be accessed at that specific point. The information it holds will already have been passed on down the line.

Comment: It sounds like you don't quite understand what `delete` actually does. If the `delete` had actually gone through, the information that has been "passed on down the line" would be invalidated, because it would be a pointer to an object that's been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the memory allocation in this code snippet

```
if (listIter->key == key) {
    temp = new Value(listIter->value);
}
```

is redundant.

Also this statement after the return statement

```
delete temp;
```

never gets the control. It should be removed.

Just write

```
if (listIter->key == key) {
    temp = &listIter->value;
}
```

Comment: I just realized I didn't change that redundant code around after trying something else lol. I changed the conditional block to temp = &listIter->value: and removed the delete but not sure how to delete that pointer to avoid the memory leak

Comment: @Cyrxs There is no memory leak in this case.